# How can I use prefix tables in database like am_user with ra-data-opencrud

Tags: react-admin

library : https://github.com/Weakky/ra-data-opencrud/

I've been struggling since 5 days and not able to fixed. I'm using prisma with mysql

if tables in database was like this User, Post . it will work fine

the issue is all tables are named like this am_user , am_post

in this library they used this
${pluralize(camelCase(resource.name))};

who is the hero who can save me? i'm not able to find any workaround

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Prisma but this question is labelled react-admin... do you have no control over your schema type definitions, react admin would only care how your schema is named i am thinking not your db tables... and there must be a way to alias the Post to target ma_post for prisma .. I had to do the same thing but i used sequelize and the functionality for aliasing is quite simple

It sounds to me like you didn't create your database and are attempting to use it with an existing database? I tried this and could not get Prisma to run, that functionality was experimental when i tried it, and i believe it still is and the introspection works for postgres only... however something like this is what i was talking about from a quick google search of prisma docs (This is for postgres)

```
type Bill @pgTable(name: "ma_bill") {
  bill: String!
  id: Int! @unique
  bill_products: [Bill_product]
}
```

This link seems to say introspection is possible for mysql tho, check it out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma-db-introspection